# How to cache images for a year but html / php for only 24 hours

Tags: php, html, .htaccess, caching

I'm new here so sorry if this is in the wrong category or something like that. Now getting to my problem. I have a website: www.windowstaan.pe.hu which also opens on a mobile app so in order to make it load fast I have enabled caching in `.htaccess` and here's its code:

```
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
<IfModule mod_expires.c>
ExpiresActive On
ExpiresByType image/jpg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/jpeg "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/gif "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType image/png "access 1 year"
ExpiresByType text/css "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType text/html "access 1 day"
ExpiresByType application/pdf "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType text/x-javascript "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType application/x-shockwave-flash "access 1 month"
ExpiresByType image/x-icon "access 1 year"
ExpiresDefault "access 1 month"
</IfModule>
## EXPIRES CACHING ##
```

Now what happens here is that any page I load in the browser can also be loaded offline which is what I wanted, but if I make any changes to the html then I'm not sure how its going to update here.

My html files are saved as `index.php`, PHP because they have some PHP code in them mainly include header, footer and a small mysql line.

Now what I want is for this homepage and every other html/php page to reload every day.

Please tell me what I need to do in `.htaccess` to set it like that.

I have tried setting html / css to 1 day there but that is not working perfectly as my app still loads the old cache. (My app is just a browser of windowsphone 8.1, IE11 probably.)

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The browser caching will base on the resource URL.

When you want to force browser to reload the new resource, you just change the URL by adding a version string.

For example, current image URL:

```
http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/af217662e49a4cbda030feae88418cdd.png
```

You can change to:

```
http://static.adzerk.net/Advertisers/af217662e49a4cbda030feae88418cdd.png?v=1
```

The version number can be controlled in your PHP code.

Version control number can be read/write from a text file in case you do not use DB.

Comment: I had seen a solution of  "fingerprints" like style.xhb32.css and then renaming it to something else when i made changes. I can manage this method for my css files since i have only 1 head file where ill need to do the renaming however der r some i cant rename bcoz many other files link to it , Here what you suggested seems to solve that problem since your file name is same but i have never added something like the  "?v1" before so I have no idea how it works. Can you please give me a small guide? I have a tutorials.php file with basic links which i need to update when i make changes.

Comment: Assume that you store the version number in somewhere (for example in DB). In your code you will have to add string after your image each time your version is changed. <img src="<?php echo $image_url . "?v=" . $version; ?>. Hope this helps

Comment: Well I haven't used a database before for storing something like that but I get your idea , Thank you ill try something like that. I probably wont need it for images i only have 4-5 pages i need to update when i make changes.

Comment: You can write the version number to a text file. Next time you just read it.

Comment: Sorry to bother you again but I have another question, I had set the cache expiry of text/html to 60 seconds but thing is if i open the website in a browser it loads the old cache even if its passed 60 seconds , only reloading it solves the problem but thats not a solution for me so i removed the html & css lines fully (only image caching then) so i cleared my browser cache then opened the page and put my device offline then i restart the browser and tried to load the page and it did load even without the text/html in .htaccess